# Constant ApplicationManager quit unexpectedly Message

Tags: mac, crash

I keep getting a window saying ApplicationManager quit unexpectedly. Every 10-20 seconds. As of 15 minutes ago. How can I fix this?

I uninstalled the spigots and the window still pops up. Here is the report (see below)

```
Process:               ApplicationManager [663]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager
Identifier:            ApplicationManager
Version:               1.1 (1.1.18)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           ApplicationManager [663]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-16 01:38:24.882 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        85F0C2D6-C4C7-5C08-4C78-827C78AE4600


Time Awake Since Boot: 690 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** CFRelease() called with NULL ***

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff901bd010 CFRelease + 912
1   ApplicationManager              0x0000000100011bfd main + 2407
2   ApplicationManager              0x0000000100001704 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95810232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e7c5a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9580f94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9211340d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff905107ba  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00000000000fc080  rdx: 0x00000000000e5ad0
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00000001000a3a00  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbffbe0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbffba0
   r8: 0x0000000000000007   r9: 0x0000000100200000  r10: 0x000000000122b847  r11: 0x0000000100200000
  r12: 0x000000010001349c  r13: 0x00000001002091b0  r14: 0x000000010040fab0  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff901bd010  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010066a000

Logical CPU:     3
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100070ff7 +ApplicationManager (1.1 - 1.1.18) <5913B635-712D-3139-9D9B-62A5EBF01BA5> /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager
    0x7fff64aa8000 -     0x7fff64ade837  dyld (353.2.1) <65DCCB06-339C-3E25-9702-600A28291D0E> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8c487000 -     0x7fff8c4b7fff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8c55a000 -     0x7fff8c574ff7  liblzma.5.dylib (7) <1D03E875-A7C0-3028-814C-3C27F7B7C079> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x7fff8cdbd000 -     0x7fff8d0a4ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1108.6 - 1108.6) <8953580E-7857-33B2-AA64-98296830D3A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff8d0a5000 -     0x7fff8d0c5fff  com.apple.IconServices (47.1 - 47.1) <E83DFE3B-6541-3736-96BB-26DC5D0100F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/Versions/A/IconServices
    0x7fff8d108000 -     0x7fff8d1c8ff7  com.apple.backup.framework (1.6.4 - 1.6.4) <A67CE7D7-AAE4-3AC0-86B7-EAF403853D09> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
    0x7fff8d263000 -     0x7fff8d27dfff  com.apple.AppleVPAFramework (1.4.3 - 1.4.3) <AE62A92E-EDA7-37AD-8AF0-7912E9381A1F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA
    0x7fff8d2ba000 -     0x7fff8d2befff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8d2c2000 -     0x7fff8d2dcff7  libextension.dylib (55.2) <3BB019CA-199A-36AC-AA22-14B562138545> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x7fff8d303000 -     0x7fff8d397fff  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 213) <8E029630-1530-3734-A446-13353F0E7AC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff8d3ae000 -     0x7fff8df2fff7  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1347.57) <B214D528-7D1C-39B2-BE36-821D417A0297> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8df4c000 -     0x7fff8df54fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (561.1.1) <62B70ECA-E40D-3C63-896E-7F00EC386DDB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8dfe4000 -     0x7fff8dfe7fff  com.apple.IOSurface (97.4 - 97.4) <AE11CFBC-4D46-30F3-BEEC-4C8131079391> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff8e150000 -     0x7fff8e15cff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <1E07769D-68DE-3BF2-8E9E-A1E98BF70D1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff8e1ab000 -     0x7fff8e6c0ffb  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (10600 - 10600.5.10) <ED4CABC6-0952-3E28-A3CD-32CA5CE22252> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
    0x7fff8e6fe000 -     0x7fff8e6feff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8e799000 -     0x7fff8e7a4ff7  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.10 - 631) <D87A64FA-64B1-3B23-BB43-ADE173C108C6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
    0x7fff8e7c1000 -     0x7fff8e7ebff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e7ec000 -     0x7fff8e824fff  com.apple.RemoteViewServices (2.0 - 99) <C9A62691-B0D9-34B7-B71C-A48B5F4DC553> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteViewServices.framework/Versions/A/RemoteViewServices
    0x7fff8e825000 -     0x7fff8e825ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8e8e5000 -     0x7fff8e8f0ff7  libkxld.dylib (2782.20.48) <28EF8328-E3E2-336A-974B-FB1BF119D55A> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8e8f1000 -     0x7fff8ea2bfff  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1237) <3C06213D-847A-3C7B-843E-6EC37113965D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff8ea30000 -     0x7fff8eaa8ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14) <06A8405D-53BA-30A9-BA8A-222099176091> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8eb28000 -     0x7fff8ef58fff  com.apple.vision.FaceCore (3.1.6 - 3.1.6) <C3B823AA-C261-37D3-B4AC-C59CE91C8241> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/FaceCore
    0x7fff8ef59000 -     0x7fff8ef64ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.3.3 - 5.3.3) <A5640275-E2A6-3856-95EF-5F0DC440B10C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff8ef65000 -     0x7fff8ef7fff3  com.apple.Ubiquity (1.3 - 313) <DF56A657-CC6E-3BE2-86A0-71F07127724C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Versions/A/Ubiquity
    0x7fff8ef80000 -     0x7fff8f02ffe7  libvMisc.dylib (516) <6739E390-46E7-3BFA-9B69-B278562326E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8f030000 -     0x7fff8f059ffb  libxslt.1.dylib (13) <AED1143F-B848-3E73-81ED-71356F25F084> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff8f05a000 -     0x7fff8f065fff  libGL.dylib (11.1.2) <BF99CC65-215A-3C7D-87D7-3F7EE6E9B3DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff8f066000 -     0x7fff8f216ff3  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.10 - 361.18) <ACA61D8F-9535-3141-8FDD-AC3EF6BF0806> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff8f670000 -     0x7fff8f67ffff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <D1E527E4-C561-352F-9457-E8C50232793C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8f682000 -     0x7fff8f684fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (11.1.2) <6EFEC4A6-2EAC-3C27-820E-C28BE71B9FCB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff8f685000 -     0x7fff8f6d4ff7  com.apple.opencl (2.4.2 - 2.4.2) <4A9574ED-15CF-3EBB-B4C0-D30F644D6C74> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff8f7be000 -     0x7fff8f7c0fff  libRadiance.dylib (1237) <9B048776-53BB-3947-8ECE-9DDA804C86B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff8f7c1000 -     0x7fff8f7c1fff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.12 - 1.12) <E5335492-7EFE-31EA-BE72-4A9CEE68D58E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff8f7c2000 -     0x7fff8f833ffb  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (360 - 375.2) <2338AF23-528F-359A-847F-8B04E49E2B84> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff8faf7000 -     0x7fff8fafcff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <BE7E51A0-B6EA-3A54-9CCA-9D88F683A6D6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff8fc77000 -     0x7fff8fcedfe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) <E1789801-3985-3949-B736-6B3378873301> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8fdae000 -     0x7fff900e1ff7  libmecabra.dylib (666.7) <0ED8AE5E-7A5B-34A6-A2EE-2B852E60E1E2> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x7fff900e2000 -     0x7fff900f9ff7  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1128) <E78CCBAA-A999-3B65-8EC9-06DB15E67C37> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff90126000 -     0x7fff90128ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff901a4000 -     0x7fff9053cff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff9055b000 -     0x7fff9056cfff  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.20.2) <6084A531-2523-39F8-B030-811FA1A32FB5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff9056d000 -     0x7fff90752ff7  libicucore.A.dylib (531.48) <3CD34752-B1F9-31D2-865D-B5B0F0BE3111> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff90777000 -     0x7fff90778fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff907c2000 -     0x7fff907dcff7  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <7760E0C2-A222-3709-B2A6-B692D900CEB1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff907dd000 -     0x7fff907e1fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (79.1) <201EF6DF-5074-3CB7-A361-398CF957A264> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff907eb000 -     0x7fff9085dfff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.20.2) <09C0518C-90DF-3FC3-96D6-34D35F72C8EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff9085e000 -     0x7fff90882ff7  com.apple.Sharing (328.16 - 328.16) <F96C7040-5FAF-3BC6-AE1E-5BF9CBE786C4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Versions/A/Sharing
    0x7fff90883000 -     0x7fff90883ff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.20.9) <FA89A113-696E-3271-8FE1-A0D7324E8481> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff9099f000 -     0x7fff909dafff  com.apple.Symbolication (1.4 - 56045) <D64571B1-4483-3FE2-BD67-A91360F79727> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication
    0x7fff909db000 -     0x7fff909f7fff  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (2.0 - 209.11) <9FF8DD11-25FB-3047-A5BF-9415339B3EEC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
    0x7fff90a90000 -     0x7fff90b14fff  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.0 - 1) <599AED3E-B689-3C40-8B91-93AD36C97658> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
    0x7fff90c8c000 -     0x7fff90cd2ff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff90d86000 -     0x7fff90d91fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) <D381EBC6-69D8-31D3-8084-5A80A32CB748> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff90ff1000 -     0x7fff9107aff7  com.apple.CoreSymbolication (3.1 - 57020.1) <85707039-0C8A-3409-B0B5-153431CC1841> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
    0x7fff9107d000 -     0x7fff9107ffff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <20F3B077-179D-3CB0-A3C1-C8602D53B4DB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff91082000 -     0x7fff91088fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.20.1) <840F5301-B55A-3078-90B9-FEFFD6CD741A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff912f7000 -     0x7fff91326ff7  com.apple.CoreServicesInternal (221.7.2 - 221.7.2) <B93D4775-149C-3698-B38C-9C50673D455C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesInternal
    0x7fff91327000 -     0x7fff91327fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10) <9D749502-A228-3BF1-B52F-A182DEEB2C4D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff91328000 -     0x7fff91735ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1128) <F9201AE7-B031-36DB-BCF8-971E994EF7C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff91736000 -     0x7fff91746ff7  libbsm.0.dylib (34) <A3A2E56C-2B65-37C7-B43A-A1F926E1A0BB> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff91793000 -     0x7fff91793fff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <C69DA8A7-B536-34BF-A93F-1C170E2C6D58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff91794000 -     0x7fff918c4fff  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 1) <466BDFA8-0B9F-3AB0-989D-F9779422926A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
    0x7fff91906000 -     0x7fff91972fff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (5.0 - 500.35.2) <5E228544-77A9-3AA5-8355-E8F6626F50E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fff91973000 -     0x7fff919f1fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (640.4 - 640.4) <20121A5E-7AB5-3624-8CF0-3562F97C8A95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff91a15000 -     0x7fff91c0f46f  libobjc.A.dylib (647) <759E155D-BC42-3D4E-869B-6F57D477177C> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff91c42000 -     0x7fff91c58ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff91c66000 -     0x7fff91ee5ff7  com.apple.CoreData (111 - 526.3) <5A27E0D8-5E5A-335B-B3F6-2601C7B976FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff91ee6000 -     0x7fff9204dffb  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.12 - 1.12) <5678FC94-456A-3F5F-BA9A-10EB6E462997> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff92067000 -     0x7fff920a7ff7  libGLImage.dylib (11.1.2) <260A4BF3-DC45-369C-A0CD-B667F9D17179> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff920a8000 -     0x7fff920acfff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <E805398D-9A92-31F8-8005-8DC188BD8B6E> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff920b4000 -     0x7fff920b5fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <2D61A2C3-C83E-3A3F-8EC1-736DBEC250AB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff920e1000 -     0x7fff920e9ff3  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1210.20.1 - 1210.20.1) <84F79D3E-7B5E-3C93-8479-35794A3F125E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff92112000 -     0x7fff9211bfff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1) <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff92136000 -     0x7fff92171fff  com.apple.QD (301 - 301) <C4D2AD03-B839-350A-AAF0-B4A08F8BED77> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff9217f000 -     0x7fff92188ff3  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <BA9F5A09-D200-3D18-9F4A-20C789291A30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
    0x7fff92214000 -     0x7fff9223afff  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.1 - 163.6) <29D4CB95-42EF-34C6-8182-BDB6F7BB1E79> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
    0x7fff92333000 -     0x7fff92340ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (36) <2DF83FBC-5C08-39E1-94F5-C28653791B5F> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff92341000 -     0x7fff92433fff  libxml2.2.dylib (26) <B834E7C8-EC3E-3382-BC5A-DA38DC4D720C> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff92d7a000 -     0x7fff92d7dfff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <9E025823-660A-30C5-A568-223BD595B6F7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff92dff000 -     0x7fff92eeffef  libJP2.dylib (1237) <A24C99BF-2360-343F-BCA1-F044E78EA0DE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff92f26000 -     0x7fff92f2bff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff936bb000 -     0x7fff9375dfff  com.apple.Bluetooth (4.3.4 - 4.3.4f4) <A1120885-F31B-3C13-9B0D-2589F391CC7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
    0x7fff93776000 -     0x7fff9380bff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0) <9150C2B7-2E6E-3509-96EA-7B3F959F049E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff93ad6000 -     0x7fff93b45fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <80883BD1-C9BA-3794-A20E-476F94DD89A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff93b46000 -     0x7fff93b47ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff93b7e000 -     0x7fff93b91ff7  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1) <8D7BA9BA-EB36-307A-9119-0B3D9732C953> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
    0x7fff93b92000 -     0x7fff93b94fff  libquarantine.dylib (76.20.1) <7AF90041-2768-378A-925A-D83161863642> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff93bd7000 -     0x7fff93c2bfff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff93c63000 -     0x7fff93c64fff  liblangid.dylib (117) <B54A4AA0-2E53-3671-90F5-AFF711C0EB9E> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff93c65000 -     0x7fff93d03fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 917.35) <8CBD1D32-4F4B-3F9A-AC65-76F2B5376FBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff93d07000 -     0x7fff93d0efff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <1581D25F-CC07-39B0-90E8-5D4F3CF84EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff93d0f000 -     0x7fff93d18fff  libGFXShared.dylib (11.1.2) <0BAF2EA8-3BC4-3BF4-ABB6-A6E0A1F3F6A5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff93d74000 -     0x7fff93d75fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <581DAD0F-6B63-3A48-B63B-917AF799ABAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff93e26000 -     0x7fff93e85fff  com.apple.AE (681.2 - 681.2) <181B3B06-2DC6-3E4D-B44A-2551C5E9CF6F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff94208000 -     0x7fff94216ff7  com.apple.opengl (11.1.2 - 11.1.2) <864B35BF-1E76-382B-8D5F-38C7282621E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff9421b000 -     0x7fff94265ff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 522.1) <E8BD41E4-7747-3CAF-807A-5CA9AD16B525> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff94266000 -     0x7fff9426dff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff94286000 -     0x7fff942b1ff3  libarchive.2.dylib (30) <8CBB4416-EBE9-3574-8ADC-44655D245F39> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff94563000 -     0x7fff9458efff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <88A22A0F-87C6-3002-BFBA-AC0F2808B8B9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff948bb000 -     0x7fff948bcff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff948f7000 -     0x7fff94bc6ff3  com.apple.CoreImage (10.3.4) <C1AE8252-A95D-3BF4-83B8-BE85E979F2CB> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fff94bc7000 -     0x7fff95403fe3  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 779.11) <DC15AADD-387C-348E-84F0-1C8BAAB1B567> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff95404000 -     0x7fff954f6ff7  libiconv.2.dylib (42) <2A06D02F-8B76-3864-8D96-64EF5B40BC6C> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff954f7000 -     0x7fff95504fff  libxar.1.dylib (255) <7CD69BB5-97BA-3858-8A8B-2F33F129E6E7> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff95525000 -     0x7fff9553eff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <790ED527-EFD2-3EA6-8C97-A8C04E96EBA7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff9553f000 -     0x7fff95550fff  libcmph.dylib (1) <46EC3997-DB5E-38AE-BBBB-A035A54AD3C0> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
    0x7fff957ab000 -     0x7fff957f8ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (10.3 - 451.1) <DE992474-0841-38A1-B4F6-46D653E454D5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff957f9000 -     0x7fff95816fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.20.48) <EAFD7BD0-0C30-3E7D-9528-F9916BA0167C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff95817000 -     0x7fff9581dff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10) <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff9581e000 -     0x7fff95846fff  libsystem_info.dylib (459.20.1) <AEB3FE62-4763-3050-8352-D6F9AF961AE6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff95847000 -     0x7fff95a54ff3  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.3.13 - 720.3.13) <69E15385-5784-3912-88F6-03B16F1C1A5C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff95a55000 -     0x7fff95a80fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 229) <F03DFAC6-6285-3176-9C6D-7CC50F8CD52A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff95a81000 -     0x7fff95a9dff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff95ce4000 -     0x7fff95fe9ff3  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 758.7) <6711FAA9-904A-3B49-9665-FC8D13B93C42> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff96055000 -     0x7fff96386fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1153.20) <F0FF3A5D-C5B7-34A1-9319-DE1EF928E58E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff96da6000 -     0x7fff96ebfffb  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 454.6) <D45790B0-E1A3-3C7D-8BA2-AB71D2CFA7FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff96ec0000 -     0x7fff96ee8fff  libxpc.dylib (559.20.9) <D35D0DB2-D7BD-3BE4-8378-062BFE545E1D> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff96ee9000 -     0x7fff96efaff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <88C7C7DE-04B8-316F-8B74-ACD9F3DE1AA1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff96fe5000 -     0x7fff9704cff7  com.apple.framework.CoreWiFi (3.0 - 300.4) <19269C1D-EB29-384A-83F3-7DDDEB7D9DAD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWiFi.framework/Versions/A/CoreWiFi
    0x7fff9718d000 -     0x7fff971fbffb  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <7697A837-98B8-3BDB-A7D2-8ED4C9ABC510> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff97260000 -     0x7fff97260fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <5BF7910B-C328-3BF8-BA4F-CE52B574CE01> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
  0x7fff98a81000 -     0x7fff98a83fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.20.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete all of the following browser extensions that you find: Searchme, Slick Savings, Amazon Shopping Assistant, Ebay Shopping Assistant, Domain Error Assistant. (See [Identifications > Examine Browser Extensions](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-identification/#extensions) for instructions on how to locate your browser extensions.) Not all of these may be present in all browsers.

Move the following items to the trash. Note that, if you don’t know how to locate a file or folder based on the paths, you should read [Locating files from paths](http://www.thesafemac.com/locating-files-from-paths/).

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.spigot.SearchProtection.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.spigot.ApplicationManager.plist
~/Library/Application Support/Spigot/
```

You will also need to change the home page and search engine settings in your browser’s preferences.

Source: [Adware Removal Guide : Spigot](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-spigot/)